# Как реализовать фиксированное соотношение экрана игры при разных физических соотношениях монитора?

Tags: c#, sfml

Я пишу мини игровой движок для своих проектов. Сейчас у меня под рукой монитор 5:4, максимальное разрешение 1280 x 1024. Если я ставлю при создании окна SFML разрешение 1280 x 720, получается следующее:

[image: screen2]

Все сплющенное (ну соотношение же не то). Если делать обычный скрин, то будет разрешение 1280 x 720 и на нем все будет нормально.

Собственно, нужно это поправить вот таким способом:

[image: screen3]

В этой игре соотношение сторон 16:9, но она запускается не сплющенной, а масштабируется. Окно имеет максимальное разрешение монитора. В настройках игры соответственно нельзя выбрать разрешение.

Опыта с таким пока не было, поэтому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас на входе должно быть разрешение экрана и желаемое соотношение сторон для вашей игры. Далее вам нужно рассчитать размер полей которые добавятся к картинке (по вертикали или горизонтали). Как это сделать?

Допустим, желаемое соотношение сторон у вас 16:9 - делим одно на другое, получаем ~1.778 (`ratio`). А разрешение экрана 1280 * 1024 (`screen_width`, `screen_height`). Используем алгоритм:

```
if (screen_height * ratio > screen_width)
  // монитор слишком узкий, будем добавлять поля сверху-снизу
  vertical_padding = screen_height - screen_width / ratio;
else
  // монитор слишком широкий, будем добавлять поля по бокам
  horizontal_padding = screen_width - screen_height * ratio;
```

Посчитаем по алгоритму выше, и получим, что для сохранения пропорций надо добавить поля сверху-снизу примерно по `304 / 2` пикселя.